# in JAVA: How to get the screen's max Frames Per Second (FBS)?

Tags: java, processing, screen, frame-rate

I'm making a game and I want my frames to be **synchronized** as the screen's max frames per second, 
 So how to get the screen's max frames per second depending on the current device, like (30 FBS, 60fbs or 120fbs, etc...) **in JAVA Language**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are referring as "Max Frames Per Second" is the refresh rate of the monitor, than you can get it with this piece of code:

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0].getDisplayMode().getRefreshRate();
```